# Use channels for websockets in a django app deployed in azure app service

Tags: websocket, azure-web-app-service, django-channels

I am trying to deploy by django app on azure app service. Everything works okay other than my sockets. I am not being able to establish websocket connection. It just works fine locally. The azure redis cache also works fine. I have tried everything from using 'wss' schemes to using non-secure ports. I donot understand how do i do this. I read somewhere that this is not possible in azure because it only allows port 80 and 443 but I dont think thats the case because even i use this config in channel layer

```
CHANNEL_LAYERS = {
    'default': {
        'BACKEND': 'channels_redis.core.RedisChannelLayer',
        'CONFIG': {
            'hosts': [('redis://:{password}@{hostname}:{port}'.format(
                password=myPassword,
                hostname=myHostname,
                port=6379
            ))],
        },
    },
}
```

i should still be able to communicate right? because its the redis cache that runs on that port which is external to the web app itself or am i missing anything? please provide some insight. Thank you.